# Getting specific column number data

Tags: linux

I want to get specific column data from a file. File is '\x01' separated (SOH is opening in notedad++ or ^A if opening in Linx). I am using below command but its not wokring

```
cut -d '\x01' -f 4,6 file_name > new_file
```

Sample file data-

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged Linux and aix?

Comment: printf is your friend: `cut -d $(printf '\001') -f 4,6`